# Update ObservableCollection from wcf service callback function

Tags: wpf, wcf, binding, client-server

I'm currently working on chat client-server application based on wcf service, which which operate in duplex mode. I have two WPF applications: Server, where service itself is hosted and Client.

Here is service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(ISendToClient))]
interface IChatService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ChatUser ClientConnect(ChatUser userName);
    [OperationContract]
    void RemoveUser(ChatUser user);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void sendNewMessage(ChatMessage message);
}
interface ISendToClient
{
    [OperationContract]
    void newUserConnected(ChatUser user);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void deliverNewMessage(ChatMessage message);

}
```

and its implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class ChatService : IChatService, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ChatService()
    {
        conectedUsers = new ObservableCollection<ChatUser>();
    }

    ISendToClient callback;

    private ObservableCollection<ChatUser> _conectedUsers;

    public ObservableCollection<ChatUser> conectedUsers
    {
        get { return _conectedUsers; }
        set
        {
            if (_conectedUsers == value) return;
            _conectedUsers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ChatUser ClientConnect(ChatUser user)
    {
        //do smth
    }
   
    public List<ChatMessage> GetNewMessages(ChatUser user)
    {
        //do smth
    }
   
    public void sendNewMessage(ChatMessage newMessage)
    {
        callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISendToClient>();
        callback.deliverNewMessage(newMessage);
    }
  
   #region PropertyChangedMembers
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

View model on client side include two additional methods

```
    public void newUserConnected(ChatUser user)
    {
        Users.Add(user); 
    }

    public void deliverNewMessage(ChatMessage message)
    {
        messHistory.Add(message);//adding message to ObservaleCollection
        //this Collection is binded to listbox, but not displays
    }
```

Server use this methods to inform client about new messages or new users logged in.

Service is correctly configured, client can connect to server and send messages,  server sends them to all users via calling deliverNewMessage() method on client side, this messages successfully added to ObservaleCollection, which is binded to listBox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Name="lst" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding messHistory}" />
```

BUT! No messages displays in listBox. I tried to do like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            messHistory.Add(message);
        }));
```

with no effect.
I guess, one little detail is missed, but have no clue.

I'd appreciate any ideas how to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have a template for `ChatMessage` in your XAML? Do you see the listbox change if you add an item to `messHistory' directly?

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov No, there is no ItemTemplate for ChatMessage. I've tried with and without it - no effect. And yes, ChatMessages, added directly, displayss in ListBox as they supposed.